# 1C 8.3. Как при прокрутке мышкой выполнить какой-нибудь код?

Tags: 1с

Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке мышкой выполнялся какой-нибудь код?
Например, прокручиваем колесо мышки и выполняется такой код:

```
Сообщить("Привет мир!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак; События перемещения курсора мыши в 1С не отслеживаются* (события не генерируются)

Единственный вариант - прокрутка на элементе формы имеющем фокус (например Таблица) и имеющем событие ПриАктивацииСтроки (которое сработает при прокрутке, т.е. при переходе на другую строку)